# What exactly will happen if I vote "yay" for the testing phase?

Tags: baker

Will I still bake on the mainnet during that phase?
How will I distinguish between testnet transactions and mainnet transactions? Are there any safeguards?

Comment: You may want to read [the official documentation about voting here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/whitedoc/voting.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the proposal passes the "Testing Vote Period" the chain is forked into two chains for the "Testing Period". Bakers are encouraged to run another `baker` and `endorser` for this test chain (setting a different PROTOCOL parameter - instructions will be provided)  My understanding is transactions are processed on both chains - users of mainnet does not have to care that there are two chains running. If the proposal passes both the "Testing Period" and the "Promotion Vote Period" the test chain becomes the main chain.